# python returning empty dictionary from module

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to return a dictionary from a module, but the dictionary is being returned empty no matter what on Python2.7 on Windows 7.  For example:

test_dict.py

```
def get_dict():
    dictiom = {'Name': 'Zara', 'Age': 7, 'Class': 'First'}
    print dictiom['Name']
    return dictiom['Name']

if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_dict()
```

get_dict.py

```
import test_dict

dict_test = test_dict.get_dict()
print dict_test
```

Running test_dict.py standalone, the print statement returns

```
Zara
```

Calling dict from get_dict.py prints

```
{}
```

This is a simplified example, but is true for other tests I have tried.

Updated to change my example mistakes.

Ok, so here's the problem part of my actual code

Search.py

```
from Bio import Entrez


def search(query):

    Entrez.email = 'me@example.com'
    handle = Entrez.esearch(db='pubmed',
                        sort='relevance',
                        retmax='50',
                        retmode='xml',
                        term=query)
    results = Entrez.read(handle)
    return results
```

main.py

```
import Search

query = 'cancer'
results = Search.search(query)
print(results)
```

results is an empty dict, but can't work out why.  But running Search.py by itself works.

Comment: `dict()` is already a built-in function to create dictionaries... Don't use built-in names for your functions/variables

Comment: good point, I forgot about that whilst I was putting this example together.  My real code doesn't use the dict example.

Answer (score 5):

**Give your funtion a different name!**
`dict` is a built in funtion.

**test_dict.py**

```
def get_dict():
    dictiom = {'Name': 'Zara', 'Age': 7, 'Class': 'First'}
    return dictiom #I think you want to return the whole dict?

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print get_dict() # print the dict as a test
```

Then you can do this

**main.py**

```
import test_dict

dict_test = test_dict.get_dict()
print dict_test
```

Comment: i think it should be "dict_test = test_dict.get_dict()"

Answer (score -1):

If you use

```
import test_dict
```

then you have to call

```
test_dict.dict()
```

If you use

```
from test_dict import dict
```

then you can call

```
dict()
```

EDIT:

You can use

```
from test_dict import dict as my_dict
```

and call

```
my_dict()
```

to prevent conflict with original `dict()`

Comment: In addition to that, I think naming the function as dict() is not recommended as it conflicts with the built in function of python.

Comment: This is awful. It encourages to use built-in function names for own made functions. NEVER do this

Comment: @furas the right way to "prevent conflict with original `dict()` is to NOT name anything `dict` at all - imagine the mess you'd get from `from test_dict import *`